# Google Maps V2 black screen flicker when adding or removing it

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an activity with 3 fragments that are toggled with tabs ..
one of those fragments has a map .. i've tried using the SupportMapFragment and just com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView in a fragment

but when i add or replace the fragment that has the map .. i get a screen black flicker .. which never happens with the other fragments

I've looked and tried to make the background of the map transparent but that didn't do me any good

Any body has a solution for that ?

Comment: how do you make transparent background to map?

Comment: you should allow a bit of a time for the map to load, try adding `new Handler().postDelayed` when you are trying to replace/add a `Map Fragment`

Comment: @Anuj could elaborate on that a little bit ? How exactly to do that ?

Comment: @NullPointerException , i mentioned in the post that it didn't work :)

Comment: @elmorabea how did you solve this problem

Comment: @Smith I actually didn't, I think a map view is just too heavy to be swapped in and out like that, I moved the Map into its own activity instead

Comment: ok but can you tell me how i can show a small map in an actiivty and onclick of that small map open the complete map

Comment: Consider using Light mode for the small map, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution for this please?

Comment: Nope, simply avoid using maps in pagers/tabs or things like that, just have its own activity. Otherwise, consider using lite mode or something

Answer (score 0):

Actually i have to post it over here, can you try using

```
 new Handler().post(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    mSupportMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
                    mFragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    mFragmentTransaction.replace(mMapWrapperLayoutStoreMap.getId(), mSupportMapFragment);
                    mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(BK_STK_SUPPORT_MAP_FRAGMENT);
                    mFragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
                }
            });
```

Also use `setTransition` as open, and do let me know if it works.

Comment: Actually I would suggest you to add the `SupportMapFragment` from java instead of adding it in the XML layout file directly, it will work.

Comment: Helps you provide time and handling to load the fragment according to your will

Comment: That helped in adding the fragment, but still same problem when removing the fragment

Comment: have you used `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(BK_STK_SUPPORT_MAP_FRAGMENT, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
` to POP your  fragment?

Comment: im sorry problem still persists, even the start now blinking again, i changed it to a separate activity

Answer (score 0):

After loading the map i.e. you will get to know in `onActivityCreated()` of the map fragment.
You should call the following method

```
private void setMapTransparent(ViewGroup group) {
    int childCount = group.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View child = group.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            setMapTransparent((ViewGroup) child);
        } else {
             child.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        }
    }
}
```

as

```
setMapTransparent((ViewGroup) fragment.getView());
```

where your `fragment` is mapFragment. Hope this helps